# Applescript dialog list from text file and adding lines to list

Tags: applescript

I can/t get my code to work when I try to make a file that contains names. I am trying to be able to add names to a file called FirstNames.txt but it wont show up as a list like I wanted it to. I kept on getting errors like "End of file error" or "Can't make type file" and then the directory "into type file." It was frustrating so I finally made it run. When I look at the contents of the list, it just says a random number each time like 1739 or 1741. It seem to be going up by twos. I am a fairly new coder when it come to applescript and hope someone can get my script to do what I want it to do. I am not worried about the file directories but I just want it to work. Any help is appreciated. Also I made comments in the code to explain my thinking.

```
set myDirectory to path to desktop as text
set myFile to myDirectory & "FirstName.txt" -- Navigates to the FirstName.txt file
display dialog myFile
try
    set fileContents to open for access file myFile with write permission
    set myList to every paragraph of (read fileContents)

    set myChoice to (choose from list myList with prompt "Choose an existing name in database or click Create New" default items "None" OK button name {"Select"} cancel button name {"Create New"})
    if myChoice is false then
        set newline to the text returned of (display dialog "What would you like your name to be?" default answer "- - - New Name - - -" buttons {"Ok"} default button 1)
        write return & newline to fileContents starting at eof
    else
        set userName to myChoice
        display dialog "Ok. Hello " & userName & "!"
    end if
    close access fileContents
on error e
    display dialog e
    try
        close access file myFile -- Closes the access in case it is already     open
    end try
end try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you're listing the file descriptor (a number) rather than the actual contents of the file.

Replace

```
choose from list fileContents
```

with

```
choose from list myList
```

But anyway I recommend to use also the built-in `write` command to write the text back. Further I added a more reliable error handling.

Consider that the script doesn't work if the file `FirstName.txt` doesn't exist yet or is empty.

```
tell application "Finder" to set myDirectory to container of (path to me) as text
set myFile to myDirectory & "FirstName.txt" -- Navigates to the FirstName.txt file

try
    set fileContents to open for access file myFile with write permission
    set myList to every paragraph of (read fileContents)

    set myChoice to (choose from list myList with prompt "Choose an existing name in database or click Create New" default items "None" OK button name {"Select"} cancel button name {"Create New"})
    if myChoice is false then
        set newline to the text returned of (display dialog "What would you like your name to be?" default answer "- - - New Name - - -" buttons {"Ok"} default button 1)
        write return & newline to fileContents starting at eof
    else
        set userName to myChoice
        display dialog "Ok. Hello " & userName & "!"
    end if
    close access fileContents
on error e
    try
        close access file myFile -- Closes the access in case it is already open
    end try
    display dialog e
end try
```

Comment: Thanks. That script works better but it still wont display the list or do anything. I have the file FirstNames.txt and it has a Name in it. It just wont show up when I run the script.

Comment: The file name in your script is `FirstName.txt` (singular).

Comment: Yes. The file is named FirstName.txt

Comment: In your first comment you wrote *FirstName**s**.txt* which is different.

Comment: Everything is correct. I put a dialog above the close access code and it seems it is going to that every time

Comment: Then an error occurs. The text file is supposed to be in the same directory as the compiled script.

Comment: It is in the same directory. I have it going to the container of the script which is the folder that the two files are in and then it goes to the FirstName.txt file

Comment: Just to be clear on what I want to do with my script is to be able to view the lines in the file through a dialog list and to be able to select or add lines to the list

Comment: Test the script by putting the text file on the desktop and change the first line to `set myDirectory to path to desktop as text`. I updated the answer to display an error message. Yes, the script should do exactly what you described.

Comment: The script runs but doesnt do anything other than going to the 'on error'

Comment: Just to be clear on what I want to do with my script is to be able to view the lines in the file through a dialog list and to be able to select or add lines to the lis

Comment: There is no error. It just trys and goes to the `on error` part

Comment: Once again, I updated the answer to display an error message. Look at the `on error` part. I just run the script again and it worked fine.

Comment: Ah. Ok. It says that File file Macintosh:Users:Jordanxxi:Desktop:FireFly.app:Contents:Resources:Scripts:TextFiles:FirstName.txt is already open.

Comment: Then insert a line `close access file myFile` after the second line of the script and run the script once. After that delete the line.

Comment: `End of file` error means the file is empty or doesn't exist. Open the file in TextEdit and Insert one name manually.

Comment: Now it says `File file Macintosh:Users:Jordanxxi:Desktop:FirstName.txt is already open.`

Comment: I am now getting two errors. The first is from error e and the second is when I try to close the file that is open. Here are the errors. `File file Macintosh:Users:Jordanxxi:Desktop:FirstName.txt is already open` and `File file Macintosh:Users:Jordanxxi:Desktop:FirstName.txt wasn’t open`

Comment: Actually the script should always close the file reliably unless you press `Cancel` after an error. To avoid that put the `display dialog e` line in the error part between both `end try` lines. To suppress the `is already open` line again insert the line `close access file myFile` after the second line, run the script once and delete the line again.

Comment: Now i get an `end of file` error but the file exists and there is a name in it

Comment: Restart your machine to get all files cleaned up.

Comment: Ok. Now I am sure it works. It works in the directory I want it to be in and all I had to do was restart Finder. Thanks again!